# Mouseflow trigger onbeforeunload not working

Tags: javascript

Call mouseflow feedback trigger on onbeforunload

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window._mfq = window._mfq || [];
  (function() {
    var mf = document.createElement("script");
    mf.type = "text/javascript"; mf.async = true;
    mf.src = "//cdn.mouseflow.com/projects/bd430861-d793-4319-964b-a8daeb7f2097.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(mf);
  })();

/* the above script is provided by mouseflow itself */

  function startSurvey() {
    window._mfq = window._mfq || []; 
    window._mfq.push(['activateFeedback', 'mouseflow_code']);
  }
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    startSurvey();
    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }
    // For Safari
    return 'Sure?';
  };
</script>
```

onbeforeunload function works well but mouseflow trigger is not triggered.

Comment: what is `_mfq` ? how can we reproduce your problem?

Comment: mfq is the mouseflow query. its provided by mouseflow itself. 

https://support.mouseflow.com/support/solutions/articles/44001534676-trigger-a-feedback-campaign-manually

Comment: Can you please provide such info in the question? Never heard of it, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not possible. Sorry, that's the short answer. The technical reason is that the only way to delay the navigation is to add an old school alert box to the `onbeforeunload` method, and then return either true or false.

I'd use the exit intent trigger instead.